# Translate a word while reading a PDF on Android

Tags: android, pdf, translation

I've been reading a lot of English books lately.

I need an Android app that can translate a word when I highlight it when I'm reading a PDF.

Comment: Translate into which language? May it cost something?

Comment: Typically translator would connect online, so I guess, no matter language.

Comment: A few more details would help here: Offline features required? Price limit? Languages / dictionary format? Be welcome to check my [list of translation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_translate). My favorite is *ColorDict* – I recommend to check this first as it matches most requirements (offline dictionaries, online services, and more).